# Overriding compareTo and Compare in java7

Tags: java, java-7

Do I need to override the equals() method when ever I override the CompareTo and Compare method in java, in order to satisfy the  Comparable contract ? Will this create any issues when I do a Collections.sort or Array.sort?

Answer (score 2):

From the Javadoc for `Comparator`

> It is generally the case, but not strictly required that (compare(x, y)==0) == (x.equals(y)). Generally speaking, any comparator that violates this condition should clearly indicate this fact. The recommended language is "Note: this comparator imposes orderings that are inconsistent with equals."

This means that you don't generally need to override `equals()`.  You probably shouldn't do this, unless you want your `Comparator` to return a non-zero comparison for two values which return `true` when compared with `equals`.

If you think that the existence of a comparison requires you to change the definition of what it means for two things to be equal, then you've probably designed something badly.

Answer (score 1):

From [`Comparable`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Comparable.html):

> The natural ordering for a class `C` is said to be consistent with equals if and only if `e1.compareTo(e2) == 0` has the same boolean value as `e1.equals(e2)` for every `e1` and `e2` of class `C`. Note that `null` is not an instance of any class, and `e.compareTo(null)` should throw a `NullPointerException` even though `e.equals(null)` returns `false`.
>
> **It is strongly recommended (though not required) that natural orderings be consistent with equals**. This is so because sorted sets (and sorted maps) without explicit comparators behave "strangely" when they are used with elements (or keys) whose natural ordering is inconsistent with equals. In particular, such a sorted set (or sorted map) violates the general contract for set (or map), which is defined in terms of the equals method.

<sup>(emphasis mine)</sup>

So you don't *need* to override `equals()` (i.e. it will not cause a problem within the standard sort methods since they use only `compareTo()`, nor does it violate the contract of `Comparable`), but it certainly wouldn't hurt.

Comment: when I have more than one way to sort a collection of objects, by making use of different comparators.. in such a scenario e1.compareTo(e2) == 0 will not be same as e1.equals(e2)...in this case if I use the class objects as keys to a collection will that cause any issue?

Comment: @paulb What kind of collection are you using?

Comment: @paulb Then there should not be a problem (as long as you don't use methods like `indexOf()` or `contains()`, since those depend on `equals()`).